# GWT2.2.0 and Uibinder Designer

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt-designer

I install the new GWT2.2.0 and its plugins for eclipse. But when I want to switch to Design Tab from Xml Source in uibinder, I get this error:
ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.dev.shell.designtime.HostedModeSupportImpl

Where is the jar file to include it in the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

No new JAR is needed , see the following link

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/installation/updatesite_3.4.html

Do give attention to the warning :
Warning: Due to a known p2 bug in Eclipse 3.4, if you previously installed using the installer or a zip file, you need to uninstall and start with a fresh copy of Eclipse

Hope this will help

Comment: yes, I got it before, I installed in a fresh copy of eclipse, as error reporter say, it needs some packages that can not resolve it